# php arrays rearaging and merging and sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
            [country] => US
            [town] => Coventry
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [observationdate] => 2015-10-01
            [country] => US
            [town] => York
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [observationdate] => 2015-10-02
            [country] => US
            [town] => York
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [observationdate] => 2015-10-02
            [country] => US
            [town] => York
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [observationdate] => 2015-10-10
            [country] => US
            [town] => York
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
            [country] => US
            [town] => York
        )

)
```

I want to sort it like this:

```
   Observation date ex 2015-10-30
     Town = Conventry
                [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                [country] => US
                [town] => Coventry
     Town = York
                  [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                  [country] => US
                  [town] => York


   Observation date ex 2015-10-02
       Town = York
                  [observationdate] => 2015-10-02
                  [country] => US
                  [town] => York
```

First part is to rearange

```
foreach($arraything as $item) {
    $items[$item['observationdate']][] = $item;

}
```

Which works fine:

I get an array arrange by date:

```
Array
(
[2015-10-30] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                [country] => US
                [town] => Coventry
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                [country] => US
                [town] => York
            )

    )

[2015-10-01] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [observationdate] => 2015-10-01
                [country] => US
                [town] => York
            )

    )

[2015-10-02] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [observationdate] => 2015-10-02
                [country] => US
                [town] => York
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [observationdate] => 2015-10-02
                [country] => US
                [town] => York
            )

    )

[2015-10-10] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [observationdate] => 2015-10-10
                [country] => US
                [town] => York
            )

    )

)
```

Now within the array arranged by dates I need to arrange it by towns

```
foreach($items AS $catid => $cat_items) {
    echo '<h3>'.$catid.'</h3>';
      foreach($cat_items AS $itema) {
      $itemsa[$itema['town']][] = $itema;
}
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($itemsa);
        echo "</pre>";

}
```

Now here starts my problem, since here is for each, each time it adds to the my new array

```
2015-10-30
Array
(
    [Coventry] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => Coventry
                )

        )

    [York] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => York
                )

        )

)
```

and by the date

```
2015-10-10
Array
(
    [Coventry] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => Coventry
                )

        )

    [York] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-30
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => York
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-01
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => York
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-02
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => York
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-02
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => York
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [observationdate] => 2015-10-10
                    [country] => US
                    [town] => York
                )

        )

)
```

I get all entries added to my new array.

How to stop that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Your code to this and try ...

```
foreach($arraything as $item) {
    $items[$item['observationdate']][$item['town']][] = $item;
}
```

No need to loop through it twice.